# How do I connect a four way key in a potentiometer?

Tags: circuit-analysis, switches, circuit-design, potentiometer, emf

[I asked this question in Physics stack exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/460647/how-do-i-connect-a-four-way-key-in-a-potentiometer) and had an answer, but I couldn't understand it well. A comment said this stack exchange was a better fit for the question.

**Question:**

How do I connect (which wire to which terminal) a four way key to a potentiometer, to compare the EMF of two cells. Circuit diagram and a four way key are shown in the pictures below.

A vague 3d representation of the whole circuit will be very much appreciated. I need to know where I have to connect the potentiometer and the cell and where do I connect the galvanometer?

[image: four way key]

[image: schematic diagram]

Comment: What is a four-way key? You show a picture, but I've never seen one of those before and I can't seem to work out what it's meant to do. Your schematic is also very odd. What are K, HR, and G? What's J? Why the long winding wire?

Comment: I hate trying to interpret schematics drawn by physicists ...

Comment: It's a kind of switch. It has four curved metal segments, which can be joined electrically by pushing a tapered plug into the gap. These are seen in physics labs, because the contact resistance is (or at least can be) very low, minimizing experimental error. Also, since all pieces are the same metal (usually brass), there are no galvanic offsets. However, it isn't at all clear how the 4-way key applies to the given schematic.

Comment: I suggest you grab a standard ohm meter and try to reverse engineer the diagram using some measured values. My guess is that the six black dots, near the E1, E2 text, are forming the four contact pairs.

Comment: Just wanted to say: My question was reanswered by a guy and it seems to be correct. Anyways, thanks for helping guys. You guys are all awesome people.

Comment: If you or anyone else feels like explaining, I'm still curious what basically everything in this schematic is. None of these are standard symbols that I recognise except the batteries and the potentiometer.

Comment: @Hearth Rh is rheostat. (G) is galvanometer. [HR] is high resistance. J for jockey, K for key. A and B are positive and negative terminals of the potentiometer. E1 and E2 are the cells connected to the Potentiometer to compare emf of. The long lines of wires are the potentiometer. Yeah, thats pretty much it. Except for the galvanometer and the high resistance, i'm pretty sure all others are standard symbols or at least, that people can make out. That is the jockey and rheostat.

Comment: @Febin.K.Dominic Physicists draw _weird_ schematics. Rh is the symbol for a potentiometer, not a rheostat.

Comment: @Hearth I dont know man. but thats what it is. It is pretty obvious for me. May be its different in different places I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Thanks to @KV18 for answering my question on Physics stackexchange* **This is his answer** (and it turned out to be right. I Asked the teacher.)

Make the connections as below. Here the dots are the connection points and cross-marks are the key knobs.

[image]

When you want to measure the deflections on the galvanometer produced by E1, remove the middle knob of the path along E2. By removing a key knob, you are leaving it in an open circuit, and hence no current passes through. If you want to measure the deflections due to E2, then remove the middle knob in between

The output of E here means the connection between the switch and the galvanometer. As to the potentiometer (assuming you are using a wooden board with the wires arranged as you have shown in the diagram), the wire is attached to the input port (a metal port at one end of the wire). Tie the rest of the wires around that same port - I.e. from the other batteries you’re comparing the end for (or electrolytes).

Answer (score 0):

If those two cells are truly isolated, then a simpler circuit is possible. You don't need both changeover switches to select between their EMF's, only one is necessary, and that can be implemented with your 4-way key.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXQCeH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Close SW1 to select V3, or SW2 to select V4

If you do want to switch the positive terminals as well, then you need a six-way key, or two of the four-way ones.

Comment: Actually, its easier this way. Idk if this is the same but yeah, this guy put it in simple terms. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/460666/222669